# Need to know with formula in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

[I have date in column A, Name in column B and Product sale data in column C. Now I want formula which gives me in return in another table, If that person has sold something on a particular date that sale data entry is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXNK1.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you have tried and also if you provided an example of the data as there are many different ways to attack this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a pivot table so that you will have the answer without any formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try `query()` with a `pivot` clause, like this:

`=query(A1:C, "select A, B, count(B) where A is not null group by A, B pivot C", 1)`

Answer (score 0):

May be it can help too

```
=Query('Sales '!A1:C, "Select Col1, Col2, Col3 Where Col3  is not null",0)
```

'Sales ' is data source worksheet
use ,1 if you don't want to include the same headers of of your data source worksheet